# The C code an issue about %d and scanf function

Tags: c

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int integerTest;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", integerTest);
    printf("You have entered a number %d \n", integerTest);
    return 0;
}
```

But after it was compiled and executed one problem occured:

> format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]

What would be not right with the code?

Answer (score 3):

You have to give the address of your integer:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int integerTest;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &integerTest); // <-- note the change
    printf("You have entered a number %d \n", integerTest);
    return 0;
}
```